# IBM WebSphere - JVM size continue to grow and GC not helping

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, websphere, heap-memory

I have a RESTful service deployed on IBM WAS 8.5.5.x, the application is functioning correctly and performing well most of the time, except occasionally (approx. once/twice a week) the JVM size is not going down, I don't see the typical 'saw tooth' pattern for JVM heap utilization.

When the heap was high, I forced a Heap Dump to look at what's holding up JVM space and all I see are related to IBM classes, can't figure out what my application could be doing wrong.

what could be using/holding these high no. of HashMap within IBM WAS ?

**Leak Suspect in IBM Memory Analyzer**

[image: Leak Suspect in IBM Memory Analyzer]

**HashMap$Node - expanded to show its children**

[image: HashMap$Node - expanded to show its children]

**com.ddtek.jdbc - is a JDBC compliant library [lib location](https://media.datadirect.com/download/eval_docs/jdbc-quickstart.htm)**

[image: class hierarchy showing all the way down]

Comment: are those allocations eventually being released, or are you having to reboot?

Comment: The `.x` in `8.5.5.x` might matter. And have you opened a support ticket with IBM?

Comment: @F Rowe - Jus one time it got healed automatically, but it took more than an hour. But they mostly needed restart the jvm. In some cases "stuck thread" was also reported.

Comment: @dbreaux - I am planning to open a case with IBM